# How can this fountain of (hot?) water coming out of the Earth arise?

Tags: geophysics

In this video from min. 7:00 is after digging in the Earth a fountain created of water. Is this due to the pressure of the water in the Earth, if so how did it get there and how did it get such a high pressure?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wdliVXxZEo

Comment: Ever been to Yellowstone?

Comment: Looks like an [artesian well](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-an-artesian-well.htm).